# Difference between new view and initial view in jsf

Tags: jsf

Can any one tell me the exact difference between new view and initial view of Restore view phase of jsf request life cycle with example? i m newbie to jsf.

Comment: I've always thought that new roughly equals to initial in English in this context. Do you want to know the distinction in the passed lifecycle phases between initial access to the view and a postback?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between JSF view instances](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912534/difference-between-jsf-view-instances)

Comment: As a word of advice, please stop reading resources targeted on JSF 1.x while using JSF 2.x. It would only end up in more confusion because many things are done differently in JSF 2.x.